# What is the right way to compare the accuracy of statistical models that predict a scalar?

Tags: statistics

If you are comparing the performance of two machine learning models trained to regress to some scalar quantity based on some input data, you might compute the MSE (mean squared error $E[(\hat{x} - x)^2]$) of each over some validation dataset. Most likely the MSE's will be different. How can you tell if the difference is statistically significant?

Comment: My first temptation was to use standard deviation of errors, but this doesn't make any sense. The mean of the error is probably near zero (unless I've trained models with systematic error) and so the MSE is about equal to the variance of the error distribution.

Comment: My first instinct would be to do repeated measurements of the two ML models and note that the sum of their differences approaches a normal distribution by CLT. And then you're in familiar territory. I don't see how two scores (one for each) is enough to do anything corresponding to significance.